# Implementing Non-Renewing Subscription type of In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I'm planning to use Non-Renewing Subscription type of In-App Purchase in my application. I have a couple of questions:

- Can I allow the user to choose the start date/time for subscription?

For example, user wants to subscribe for a week, starting from 14 November (Wednesday) to 20 November (Tuesday).

- Can I allow the user to subscribe for different time periods (in future)?

For example, today is 14 November and user wants to subscribe for a week in November (Monday, 19 November to Sunday, 25 November) and for December (Saturday, 1 December to Monday, 31 December).

- Can I control the subscription logic from a server (via web services)?

For example, when user purchases a subscription for a week, the information is stored on the server. On consecutive logins, on same or different device, the status of the subscription will be received from the server. Note that the application (inherently) requires a Register/Login mechanism to work.

p.s. I'm not using Auto-Renewing Subscription type of In-App Purchase for a number for reasons, including the fact that I can't because of the following guideline:

> 11.15 Apps may only use auto renewing subscriptions for periodicals (newspapers, magazines), business Apps (enterprise, productivity, professional creative, cloud storage) and media Apps (video, audio, voice), or the App will be rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my experience, here are the responses to my own questions.

> Can I allow the user to choose the start date/time for subscription?

Yes.

> Can I allow the user to subscribe for different time periods (in future)?

I ended up not doing that, but based on the feedback I received, you can.

> Can I control the subscription logic from a server (via web services)?

Yes.